# Deny php execution in /wp-includes - using .htaccess in /wp-includes VS root folder

Tags: php, htaccess, security, tinymce

Trying to secure my WP site. In an attempt to deny php execution from the wp-includes folder wondering if these two methods are effectively doing the same thing?

1) add new .htaccess file to root of wp-includes folder with following code:

```
<Files *.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```

but this disables tinymce.

2) add this code to top of existing .htaccess in root of WP install:

```
# Block the include-only files.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Are these doing the same thing? Been using method #1 but need to make tinymce accessible now.

Comment: I doubt this will actually improve your WP security, instead it would be better to make that folder read only and use version control to update it. Especially since there are no files that can be executed from userland in that folder anyway, they would all abort execution anyway or fail to run

Comment: Do you think it's even necessary to add protection here? It's hosted on WPengine and I've never had issues - I was just following some tutorials about WP security...

Comment: I would be vary wary of those tutorials, WP Engine are unlikely to be happy with you doing that, and a lot of it has no benefit other than security theatre to make you feel like you've done something. The biggest impact you can have on your security is in your theme and plugin code, and not doing stupid things like having `[php]` shortcodes or allowing arbitrary javascript, or not checking file types on custom uploaders, missing escaping, etc etc

Comment: Removed all the garbage, thank you!!  If you have any reliable resources you'd recommend reading about theme security best practices I would be grateful

Comment: "deny php execution" - those directives don't strictly "deny PHP execution", they prevent PHP files being requested over HTTP (by the end user). PHP files in those directories can still be executed if called from another script on the server. Depending on your server config, you can disable PHP execution on a per-directory using [PHP's `engine` config option](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/apache.configuration.php).

Comment: If you were to ever disable PHP execution like this, it would be in the uploads folder, but I would expect WP Engine already do that and many other things. Ask them! They're a managed host so they should be doing a lot of the server level stuff to secure a site already